# Calling functions from .dll class and connecting it with my custom class C#

Tags: c#

I have a library (not mine) that I use for meshes in C# and this library is compiled in .dll. So I do not have access to code inside.

However I wrote my custom static class, that is full of helper functions to that library.

I just noticed that every single function is written like this:

```
public static class MeshUtilities{

 public static functionA (Mesh mesh, some other variable)
 { ... }

 public static functionB (Mesh mesh, some other variable)
 { ... }

 public static functionC (Mesh mesh, some other variable)
 { ... }

}
```

In my application I call those functions as MeshUtilities.function(mesh, some other variable)

But as you see every single function starts from type Mesh mesh.

Is there any way that I could write this helper class in such a way that I would only need to write mesh.FunctionFromMyCustomHelperClass(some other variables) ?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make it an extension class?

```
public static class MeshUtilities{

 public static functionA (this Mesh mesh, some other variable)
 { ... }

 public static functionB (this Mesh mesh, some other variable)
 { ... }

 public static functionC (this Mesh mesh, some other variable)
 { ... }

}
```

And call it like this:

```
Mesh ourMesh = new Mesh();
ourMesh.functionC(someVariable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I very much misunderstand your last paragraph, [that's an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method). Add `this` before the first parameter's type:

```
public static class MeshUtilities{

     public static void functionA (this Mesh mesh, object someOtherVariable)
     {
         mesh.SomeOtherMethod(baz.foobar());
         //  etc.
     }
```

And use like so:

```
var mesh = new Mesh();

mesh.functionA(3);
```